# Account Linking With Dialogflow Custom Action

Tags: actions-on-google

Hey there I want to use Account linking. I want Google Sign In only and I will be using dialogflow custom actions. I have added a dialogflow intent having actions_intent_SIGN_IN name (there is a built-in one). Then I went to Action Console and chose Account Linking. Then chose Google SignIn Only and. Now is it asking for Authorisation URL and token URL. What should I do now? There are many posts which use OAuth etc. But All I want is use Google Sign In inside a google service i.e assistant. Can someone post a step by step guide? I tried doing many things but not getting anywhere close.

Answer (score 0):

This shows you step by step what you should do https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in. For Google Sign-In only you don't need to pass in anything for the URLs.

Comment: I was expecting some logic flow which may include some code. I specifically said that docs are outdated and you are posting the same.

Comment: The code in the docs work fine for me. It's just the configuration that is slightly outdated, but you just don't need to pass anything in the URLs.